# How to stop image view to ask for coding system

Tags: character-encoding

Every time I open any image (png, jpg etc.) I'm confronted with the warning below and `helm` prompting for a coding system.

What can I do?

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ‘ *temp file*’:
  (utf-8-unix (1 . 4194303) (2 . 4194264) (3 . 4194303) (4 . 4194273) (6 .
  4194302) (34 . 4194194) (46 . 4194200) (70 . 4194210) (82 . 4194218) (106 .
  4194226) (118 . 4194234))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
  utf-8-unix cannot encode these:           ...

Click on a character (or switch to this window by ‘SPC w w’
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where ‘SPC u C-x =’ will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with SPC w p p and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

  raw-text no-conversion
```

[image: img]

Comment: Could you `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` and then type `C-g` at the coding system prompt and copy the backtrace into your question?  That might help to identify why this is happening.

Comment: Also, does this happen if you run `emacs -Q` and open the same file?

Comment: You could try to debug it using `M-x debug-on-entry` `select-safe-coding-system` as described in the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/69158/26163)